# CFGs for languages L1 and L2 where #a's > #b's and #a's >= #b's

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

Regarding the language L2 where the #a's >= #b's I thought of the following:

```
S -> SaSbS 
S -> SbSaS
S -> SaS
S -> ε
```

When it comes to L1 I thought of utilising L2 in the following way and give an infinite degree of freedom to the number of a's:

```
S -> L1 A L1
A -> aA'
A'-> aA' | ε
```

I know that there are similar questions answered on this topic but I wanted to make my own attempt since the answers provided are not the same and two distinct CFGs may produce the same language. Are the CFGs provided correct?